# Python Windows Connect via a specific interface

Tags: python, interface, bind

i'm trying to connect to a host via a specific network interface but it failed. Here http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/advanced.html in paragraph 4.10 it says the bind() must be call to a ip interface then make a connect(). Here is the code:

```
import socket
from time import sleep

socketLocale= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socketLocale.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_KEEPALIVE,1)
socketLocale.settimeout(10)

#10.179.51.239 is the ip address of one of my network interfaces
socketLocale.bind(("10.179.51.239",45365))
#or socketLocale.bind(("10.179.51.239",0))

socketLocale.connect(("stackoverflow.com",80))

sleep(10)
socketLocale.close()
```

The error is:
    [Errno 10049]The requested address is not valid in its context

Comment: Are you 200% sure that the IP address you're passing to `bind()` is one of the local IPs? The code runs fine for me, but produces the error you described if I give it an address that isn't configured locally.

Comment: Carte PPP InternetEverywhere :

   Suffixe DNS propre … la connexion. . . : 
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 10.179.51.239
   Masque de sous-r‚seau. . . .ÿ. . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Passerelle par d‚faut. . . .ÿ. . . . . : 0.0.0.0

 Here is my ipconfig

Comment: the bind works well in C++ but fails in python. what is wrong

Comment: Does the address show up in the results of `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())`?

Comment: (Make that `socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())`)

Comment: i have two interfaces the 3G and the VPN. and no it shows the ip of the vpn 25.52.5.2. with `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` but when i try with this ip the same error produce. i have tested both ip in C++ it works well. i guess python is the problem. but with `socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())` i got it.